Nested List placement issue?
I am trying to build a dynamic sub-list items navigation bar
I rendered the navigation bar but the issue is with placement of the sub-list items, but there is issue with the placement of the sub-list items
the first-level sub-list should come directly below the nav the the nested subitems should come side by side
But  I'm getting

but it should be under Events and if the upcoming/Past events has the sublist it should come to the right
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TestTitle</title>
    <style>
        
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    // JSON data for navigation items
    const navItems={
  "navigationItems": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Home",
      "url": "/",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Introduction",
          "url": "/introduction",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "title": "Company Overview",
              "url": "/introduction/company-overview",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 4,
                  "title": "Mission Statement",
                  "url": "/introduction/company-overview/mission-statement"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "title": "News",
          "url": "/news",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 6,
              "title": "Press Releases",
              "url": "/news/press-releases",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 7,
                  "title": "Latest Announcements",
                  "url": "/news/press-releases/latest-announcements"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "title": "About Us",
      "url": "/about",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 9,
          "title": "Our Team",
          "url": "/about/our-team",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 10,
              "title": "Management",
              "url": "/about/our-team/management",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 11,
                  "title": "Executive Team",
                  "url": "/about/our-team/management/executive-team"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "title": "History",
          "url": "/about/history",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 13,
              "title": "Founding",
              "url": "/about/history/founding",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 14,
                  "title": "Early Days",
                  "url": "/about/history/founding/early-days"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "title": "Services",
      "url": "/services",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 16,
          "title": "Consulting",
          "url": "/services/consulting",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 17,
              "title": "Strategy",
              "url": "/services/consulting/strategy",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 18,
                  "title": "Business Strategy",
                  "url": "/services/consulting/strategy/business-strategy"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "title": "Development",
          "url": "/services/development",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 20,
              "title": "Software",
              "url": "/services/development/software",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 21,
                  "title": "Custom Software",
                  "url": "/services/development/software/custom-software"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "title": "Products",
      "url": "/products",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 23,
          "title": "Software",
          "url": "/products/software",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 24,
              "title": "Enterprise Solutions",
              "url": "/products/software/enterprise-solutions",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 25,
                  "title": "ERP Systems",
                  "url": "/products/software/enterprise-solutions/erp-systems"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 26,
          "title": "Hardware",
          "url": "/products/hardware",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 27,
              "title": "Desktops",
              "url": "/products/hardware/desktops",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 28,
                  "title": "Gaming PCs",
                  "url": "/products/hardware/desktops/gaming-pcs"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "title": "Blog",
      "url": "/blog",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 30,
          "title": "Tech News",
          "url": "/blog/tech-news",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 31,
              "title": "Latest Trends",
              "url": "/blog/tech-news/latest-trends",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 32,
                  "title": "AI Innovations",
                  "url": "/blog/tech-news/latest-trends/ai-innovations"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 33,
          "title": "Lifestyle",
          "url": "/blog/lifestyle",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 34,
              "title": "Travel",
              "url": "/blog/lifestyle/travel",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 35,
                  "title": "Top Destinations",
                  "url": "/blog/lifestyle/travel/top-destinations"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 36,
      "title": "Support",
      "url": "/support",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 37,
          "title": "FAQs",
          "url": "/support/faqs",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 38,
              "title": "Account Issues",
              "url": "/support/faqs/account-issues",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 39,
                  "title": "Password Recovery",
                  "url": "/support/faqs/account-issues/password-recovery"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 40,
          "title": "Contact Us",
          "url": "/support/contact",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 41,
              "title": "Customer Service",
              "url": "/support/contact/customer-service",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 42,
                  "title": "Help Center",
                  "url": "/support/contact/customer-service/help-center"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 43,
      "title": "Events",
      "url": "/events",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 44,
          "title": "Upcoming",
          "url": "/events/upcoming",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 45,
              "title": "Webinars",
              "url": "/events/upcoming/webinars",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 46,
                  "title": "Tech Talks",
                  "url": "/events/upcoming/webinars/tech-talks"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 47,
          "title": "Past Events",
          "url": "/events/past",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 48,
              "title": "Workshops",
              "url": "/events/past/workshops",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 49,
                  "title": "Training Sessions",
                  "url": "/events/past/workshops/training-sessions"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "title": "Partners",
      "url": "/partners",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 51,
          "title": "Affiliates",
          "url": "/partners/affiliates",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 52,
              "title": "Strategic Partners",
              "url": "/partners/affiliates/strategic-partners",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 53,
                  "title": "Global Partners",
                  "url": "/partners/affiliates/strategic-partners/global-partners"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 54,
          "title": "Sponsors",
          "url": "/partners/sponsors",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 55,
              "title": "Gold Sponsors",
              "url": "/partners/sponsors/gold-sponsors",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 56,
                  "title": "Platinum Partners",
                  "url": "/partners/sponsors/gold-sponsors/platinum-partners"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "title": "Community",
      "url": "/community",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 58,
          "title": "Forums",
          "url": "/community/forums",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 59,
              "title": "Technical Support",
              "url": "/community/forums/technical-support",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 60,
                  "title": "Bug Reports",
                  "url": "/community/forums/technical-support/bug-reports"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 61,
          "title": "Events",
          "url": "/community/events",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 62,
              "title": "Meetups",
              "url": "/community/events/meetups",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 63,
                  "title": "Local Meetups",
                  "url": "/community/events/meetups/local-meetups"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 64,
      "title": "Careers",
      "url": "/careers",
      "subItems": [
        {
          "id": 65,
          "title": "Job Openings",
          "url": "/careers/job-openings",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 66,
              "title": "Full-time",
              "url": "/careers/job-openings/full-time",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 67,
                  "title": "Engineering",
                  "url": "/careers/job-openings/full-time/engineering"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 68,
          "title": "Internships",
          "url": "/careers/internships",
          "subItems": [
            {
              "id": 69,
              "title": "Summer Internships",
              "url": "/careers/internships/summer-internships",
              "subItems": [
                {
                  "id": 70,
                  "title": "Engineering Internships",
                  "url": "/careers/internships/summer-internships/engineering-internships"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


// Function to render navigation items recursively
function renderList(items) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');

  items.forEach(item => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = item.url;
    a.textContent = item.title;
    li.appendChild(a);

    // Recursively render subItems if they exist
    if (item.subItems) {
      const sublist = renderList(item.subItems);
      li.appendChild(sublist);
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);
  });

  return ul;
}

// Render the navigation menu
function renderNavigation() {
  const navContainer = document.getElementById('nav-container'); // Make sure you have an element with this ID in your HTML
  const navList = renderList(navItems.navigationItems);
  navContainer.appendChild(navList);
}

// Call the render function on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', renderNavigation);

    </script>
    <style>

    #nav-container{
        position: relative;
    }     

    ul{
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul li ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
    }


    ul li{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    li:hover > ul{
        display: block;
    }
    li > ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
    }


    </style>

</head>

<body>
  

  <div id="nav-container"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>


What are you using to build this functionality? You've tagged this as LWC, but your code snippet has style and script tags in it and no JS controller.
